# Inno Setup if and language

Tags: installation, package, inno-setup, pascal

I wanted to know how to control the language of inno setup, I would like that when the user selects the English inno setup after installation eliminates the Italian language files, but if the user selects the Italian language, I would like that after the installation would remove the language file English. I tried this code but does not work:

```
[InstallDelete]
#if {language} = "english"
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\english.txt"
#if {language} = "italian"
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\italian.txt"
#endif
```

Thanks.

**Sorry for my English.**

Answer (score 4):

Directives are evaluated at compile time, and in any case [InstallDelete] section is processed at the beginning of the setup. The easiest approach for your case, I believe, is to not install the file in the first place if the user has not chosen the corresponding setup language:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "it"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"

[Files]
Source: "english.txt"; DestDir: "{commondesktop}"; Languages: en;
Source: "italian.txt"; DestDir: "{commondesktop}"; Languages: it;
```

If I have somehow misunderstood the question, you can use the `DeleteFile` support function in code to delete a file, for instance in a `CurStepChanged` procedure while `CurStep` is 'ssDone' or 'ssPostInstall'.

Comment: You won't need to delete the file if you haven't installed it, no?

Comment: There is also the built in [`Languages:`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_commonparams.htm#Languages) parameter removing the need for the `IsLang()` custom function.

Comment: Thanks @Deanna, I didn't know it. I'd vote if you posted it as an answer.